# SQL Server equivalent of TO_CHAR and format conversion

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I would like to know how I can convert the oracle instruction `TO_CHAR(MY_COLUMN_NAME, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3')` in SQL Server. (The column containing a date)

I think I can use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), MY_COLUMN_NAME, 120);` in SQL Server to convert a date to the YYYY-MM-DD format but what about the YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3 format?

Comment: Have you tried using a larger varchar? 10 characters is only enough to hold the YYYY-MM-DD; anything after that would be truncated.

Comment: Try cast (cast (MY_COLUMN_NAME as date) as varchar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Format().  I should note that it is NOT a performer, but does have some nice functionality

```
Select DateTime   = GetDate()
      ,Formatted = format(GetDate(),'yyyyMMddHHmmssfff')
```

Returns

```
DateTime                  Formatted
2017-04-26 12:04:01.363   20170426120401363
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the performance. In tests on my system and on [DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=22040fa9c78a8ce949a3fc62b06035f8), `CONVERT` performs about 15 times faster on a sample of 100,000 rows. It is not exactly a robust test, but it does show a large enough difference to be considered significant (in my opinion).

Comment: @GarethD I've run some benchmarks as well.  But I've witnessed results closer to 100 percent rather than 100 times ... for example 140ms vs 312ms.    Love the dbfiddle!

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL 2012+ there are `FORMAT` function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmssfff')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format command (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) where you have access to all of the functionality that .net provides. Presumably you are using a relatively current version of sql server - which is information you should provide when posting questions btw. As an example (and I don't know what your oracle format generates):

```
declare @x datetime; 
set @x = '20170415 23:55:01.003';
select @x, FORMAT(@x, 'yyyyMMdd HHmmss.fff');
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior to SQL Server 2012, you could use [**`convert()`** styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and `replace()`

```
select 
    iso_format = convert(varchar(23),getdate(),121)
  , numbers_only = replace(replace(replace(replace(
          convert(varchar(23),getdate(),121)
           ,'-',''),':',''),' ',''),'.','')
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YMMG65247

returns:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+
|       iso_format        |   numbers_only    |
+-------------------------+-------------------+
| 2017-04-26 18:15:42.590 | 20170426181542590 |
+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

Note that `format()` does have some performance issues, and this may be a reasonable alternative even on SQL Server 2012+. [`format()` is nice and all, but… - Aaron Berrtand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)